# Migration of questions with answers

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492876/ansible-ad-hoc-commands-only-work-as-sudo-unless-im-in-the-hosts-directory) "Ansible" question just now and it has an answer that points out that it's actually entirely unrelated to Ansible but more to a utility that the OP was using that was causing issues with permissions.

The question-answer combo seems far more suited to SuperUser rather than here as it's actually got nothing to do with programming.

I know migrations are typically for trying to find a better niche for the question so that the OP can get their answer but is there any mileage in also using them to better catalogue this information?